# Parsers should load imported ontologies using the makeImportLoadRequest method

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I want to import two ontology (join them) in one (third) Ontology, I created a new Ontology with the IRI that I like. and the I click on import onoltogies and I selected the path to one of my ontologies and click import.

I get the following error **though the classes and the properties have been imported but i am asking maybe this error means something**

```
LogRecord{ERROR, 1456742613800, Runtime Warning: Parsers should load imported ontologies using the makeImportLoadRequest method., AWT-EventQueue-0}
```

I saw that error in that red sign that appears in the top right of my protege though as i said, the classes and properties have been imported successfully.

How can I solve that error please ?

#### Update

In the log, all the log are `info`, exception this one `error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is not relevant. It means there's a bug in the code - loading of imports is supposed to happen in a precise way, but here it is happening differently.

As long as your imports are being loaded as you expect, you do not need to worry about it. If you wish for the bug to be fixed, you'll have to raise the issue with Protege or the OWL API projects, but it will be necessary to have examples of the ontologies you're using to reproduce the issue.